# Google Sheets - running script when opening on iPhone

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I've created my first very simple script, it might not be that efficient, but it works! When I open the workbook it runs the script and gives me a random variable, which is then used to look up a cell in another sheet.

```
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C2').setFormula('=RANDBETWEEN(2,counta(Opskrifter!A:A))');
  var value = spreadsheet.getRange("C2").getValue();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C2').setValue(value);
};
```

I want to be able to open the workbook on my iPhone either from Google Drive or a link in Chrome (on a published web page?) and run the script on opening. But the opOpen() only seems to work when I open it on my computer?

I've tried doing it as a trigger event and using a button, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765325) that prevents onOpen() functions to work on mobile devices (Android and iOS). On the other hand, onEdit() does work.

You can click on the star next to the issue number to subscribe and receive updates. It will also give more priority to the bug.